# Removing white space on inserting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

On inserting data in mysql a space appears first, how to remove it? aim trying to use trim but all code failed. Can someone give me some clues?

```
else {

$artist = $xml->SERVERTITLE;
$title = $xml->SONGTITLE; {
$pieces = explode("-", $title);
$pieces = trim($pieces[1]);



 // performing sql query

 $sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `artist`) VALUES ('$pieces[1]',     '$pieces[0]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now()";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

 if (!$result) {
            echo 'MYSQL ERROR';
        } else  {
        echo 'sucesso';
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: $pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
$pieces[1] = trim($pieces[1]); 
trim() function removes whitespace in a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `{`

```
$xml->SONGTITLE; { // remove it
```

So you have:

```
$pieces = trim($pieces[1]);
```

Now `$pieces` is a **string**. And doing `$pieces[0]` returns first symbol of string. Error is that you overwrite `$pieces` value and still think that it's an array. As others supposed use:

```
$pieces[0] = trim($pieces[0]);
$pieces[1] = trim($pieces[1]);
```

Comment: So explain then - what for do you need that?

Comment: Have you checkd that there's `-` symbol in `$xml->SONGTITLE`? You know what happens when there's no such symbol?

Comment: There is always that symbol, as it is a xml from a shoutcast server.

Comment: string(27) "Happy Lovers At Last United" sucesso

Answer (score 0):

```
$pieces = explode("-", $title);
$title = trim($pieces[1]);
$artist = trim($pieces[0]);
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `artist`) VALUES ('$title','$artist') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = now()";
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function trim_value(&$value) 
{ 
   $value = trim($value); 
}

array_walk($pieces, 'trim_value');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.